# What is considered a very large dataset for the Python Beam SDK?

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm working on setting up a Google Dataflow using the Python 2.31 Beam SDK. It's a pretty straight forward task that reads from a BigQuery table, performs some logic to append a few additional columns to the data, and then writes the results back to a separate BigQuery table.

This has successfully run for 48 billion rows of data, but fails when run for around 80 billion rows. The issue appears to be with the writing to Big Query step, as I can see errors in the diagnostics page mentioning steps in the Write Results to BigQuery phase being blocked or taking a long time. I can also see Runtime Errors with Instruction id not being registered in that same phase.

The SDK documentation notes there may be issues writing very large datasets with Python. https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/google-bigquery/#limitations. Based on that, I did change the code around a bit to write to 5 different tables instead of a single one, but ran into similar issues.

My assumption is that limitation is what I'm running into here. I'm unclear on how to find where that limitation is or if there's a decent workaround for it. I just found some info about streaming inserts, so I'm going to do some testing with that to see if that works better than using file loads.

For reference, this is a slightly redacted version of the code for the non partitioned attempt:

```
from __future__ import division
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io import ReadFromText
from apache_beam.io import WriteToText,WriteToBigQuery

from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions, GoogleCloudOptions, StandardOptions, SetupOptions, \
    WorkerOptions
import pandas as pd
import logging

class JoiningDoFn2(beam.DoFn):
    # Do lazy initializaiton here. Otherwise, error messages pop up, associated with "A large DoFn instance that is serialized for transmission to remote workers.""
    def __init__(self):
        #self._pickle_file = None
        from google.cloud import storage
        import pickle as pkl
        self._storage = storage
        self._pkl = pkl

    def setup(self):
        bucket = self._storage.Client().get_bucket("GCS BUCKET NAME")
        blob = bucket.get_blob('ubi/dataflow/density_balltree2.pkl')
        self._pickle_file = self._pkl.loads(blob.download_as_bytes())        

    def process(self, gps_element):
        import numpy as np 

        # Get coordinates in radians
        balltree = self._pickle_file[0]
        density_mapping = self._pickle_file[1]
        nn_lat_mapping  = self._pickle_file[2]
        nn_lon_mapping  = self._pickle_file[3]
        
        distances, closest_indicies = balltree.query(np.asarray((gps_element['GPSLatitude']*np.pi/180,gps_element['GPSLongitude']*np.pi/180)).reshape(1, -1),k=1)

    # Use mapping to get traffic density from closest index
        gps_element['traffic_density'] = density_mapping[closest_indicies[0][0]]
        gps_element["distance_to_nn"] = 6371 * distances[0][0]

        gps_element['nn_lat'] = nn_lat_mapping[closest_indicies[0][0]]
        gps_element['nn_lon'] = nn_lon_mapping[closest_indicies[0][0]]
 
        yield gps_element
        
        
DESTINATION_TABLE_CONFIGS = {
    "table": "TARGET TABLE NAME",

    "dataset": "TARGET DATASET NAME",

    "project":  "PROJECT NAME",

    "schema": "driverid:STRING,    tripid:STRING,        TimeStamp:NUMERIC,\
                         GPSLatitude:FLOAT64,        GPSLongitude:FLOAT64, \
                         traffic_density:FLOAT64,    distance_to_nn:FLOAT64,\
                         nn_lat:FLOAT64,        nn_lon:FLOAT64",

    "create_disposition": beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,

    "write_disposition": beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND

}


pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(
    runner='DataflowRunner',
    project='PROJECT NAME',
    #job_name=job_name,
    region='us-east4',
    subnetwork= 'SUBNETWORK INFO',
    use_public_ips=False,
    staging_location = f'gs://GCS BUCKET NAME/ubi/dataflow/' + 'staging/',
    temp_location = f'gs://GCS BUCKET NAME/ubi/dataflow/' + 'temp/',    
    machine_type = "n1-standard-1",
    max_num_workers = 600,
    #num_workers = 500,
    autoscaling_algorithm='THROUGHPUT_BASED'#None
    #disk_size_gb = 30

)

class DataFlowPipeline:
    """THIS IS THE CLASS THAT ACTUALLY RUNS THE JOB"""
    def run(self):
        """This is the job runner it holds the beam pipeline"""

        with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:

            query_sql =  """
SQL QUERY TEXT
"""            
            
            processed_trips = p | 'Read records from BQ' >>beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(query=query_sql, use_standard_sql=True) | 'Add traffic density' >> beam.ParDo(JoiningDoFn2()) | 'Write result to BQ' >> WriteToBigQuery(**DESTINATION_TABLE_CONFIGS)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)

    print('setting up config for runner...')
    trainer = DataFlowPipeline()
    trainer.run()
    print('The runner is done!')
```

And this is a slightly redacted version of the attempt outputting to 5 different tables:

```
from __future__ import division
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io import ReadFromText
from apache_beam.io import WriteToText,WriteToBigQuery

from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions, GoogleCloudOptions, StandardOptions, SetupOptions, \
    WorkerOptions
import pandas as pd
import logging

class JoiningDoFn2(beam.DoFn):
    # Do lazy initializaiton here. Otherwise, error messages pop up, associated with "A large DoFn instance that is serialized for transmission to remote workers.""
    def __init__(self):
        #self._pickle_file = None
        from google.cloud import storage
        import pickle as pkl
        self._storage = storage
        self._pkl = pkl

    def setup(self):
        bucket = self._storage.Client().get_bucket('GCS BUCKET NAME')
        blob = bucket.get_blob('ubi/dataflow/density_balltree2.pkl')
        self._pickle_file = self._pkl.loads(blob.download_as_bytes())        

    def process(self, gps_element):
        import numpy as np

        # Get coordinates in radians
        balltree = self._pickle_file[0]
        density_mapping = self._pickle_file[1]
        nn_lat_mapping  = self._pickle_file[2]
        nn_lon_mapping  = self._pickle_file[3]
        
        distances, closest_indicies = balltree.query(np.asarray((gps_element['GPSLatitude']*np.pi/180,gps_element['GPSLongitude']*np.pi/180)).reshape(1, -1),k=1)

    # Use mapping to get traffic density from closest index
        gps_element['traffic_density'] = density_mapping[closest_indicies[0][0]]
        gps_element["distance_to_nn"] = 6371 * distances[0][0]

        gps_element['nn_lat'] = nn_lat_mapping[closest_indicies[0][0]]
        gps_element['nn_lon'] = nn_lon_mapping[closest_indicies[0][0]]
 
        yield gps_element
        
        
DESTINATION_TABLE_CONFIGS = {
    "dataset": "TARGET DATASET",

    "project":  "PROJECT NAME",

    "schema": "driverid:STRING,    tripid:STRING,        TimeStamp:NUMERIC,\
                         GPSLatitude:FLOAT64,        GPSLongitude:FLOAT64, \
                         traffic_density:FLOAT64,    distance_to_nn:FLOAT64,\
                         nn_lat:FLOAT64,        nn_lon:FLOAT64",

    "create_disposition": beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,

    "write_disposition": beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND
}


pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(
    runner='DataflowRunner',
    project='PROJECT NAME',
    #job_name=job_name,
    region='us-east4',
    subnetwork= 'SUBNETWORK INFO',
    use_public_ips=False,
    staging_location = 'gs://GCS BUCKET/ubi/dataflow/' + 'staging/',
    temp_location = 'gs://GCS BUCKET/ubi/dataflow/' + 'temp/',        
    machine_type = "n1-standard-1",
    max_num_workers = 500,
    #num_workers = 50,
    #disk_size_gb = 30,
    autoscaling_algorithm='THROUGHPUT_BASED'#None


)

class DataFlowPipeline:
    """THIS IS THE CLASS THAT ACTUALLY RUNS THE JOB"""        
    
    def run(self):
        """This is the job runner it holds the beam pipeline"""   

        #How many splits the data should do. Make sure to set up the appropriate amount of p_ values below to match this number if it's changed.
        PARTITIONS = 5

        with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:

            query_sql =  """
SQL QUERY TEXT
"""            

            partition = (
                p | 'Read records from BQ' >>beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(query=query_sql, use_standard_sql=True) 
                | 'Add traffic density' >> beam.ParDo(JoiningDoFn2())
                | 'Split output' >> beam.Partition(lambda element, PARTITIONS: round(element["TimeStamp"]) % PARTITIONS, PARTITIONS) 
            )
            
            for x in range(PARTITIONS):
                partition[x] | f'Write Partition {x}' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(table=f'TARGET TABLE NAME_{x}', **DESTINATION_TABLE_CONFIGS)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)

    print('setting up config for runner...')
    trainer = DataFlowPipeline()
    trainer.run()
    print('The runner is done!')
```

Comment: 80 billion rows - is that around ~40 TB or so?

Comment: It's a pretty small table, width wise. We are only pulling across 5 columns. So the 80 billion row source query shows it will scan 6.3 TB of data if run directly in BigQuery. The resulting table with the additional columns looks like it would be approximately 8.1 TB.

Comment: this should not be too much for the Beam pipeline. We had a perfomance issue recently, that will be fixed in 2.33.0 - in the meantime, can you try running `Read(BigQuerySource(...))` with the same parameters?

Comment: Sure, I can try with the Read(BigQuerySource(...)) version. I just ran it on a small dataset to check my syntax, and it worked. I'll have to hold the big run until tomorrow though, as it eats up a lot of resources.

Does Read(BigQuerySource(...)) behave differently behind the scenes than ReadFromBigQuery(...)?

Comment: yes - BigQuerySource runs within the Dataflow runner's backend - it's an older implementation, but it doesn't suffer from the performance issue that ReadFromBQ does

Comment: I kicked off the test run at 2 pm on 9/3. It didn't start processing elements until 12:30 pm on 9/4. It ran until 9/5 around 9:30 am and then crashed after processing 67 billion rows.
Then I realized I'd kicked it off with a flag we've been using for the other runs that was likely in opposition to the older run method: --experiments=use_runner_v2
I restarted the job without that, and it was pulling records within an hour and a half of starting up. 
I had to kill the job as it was impacting other users, but it seemed to be pulling records more consistently. Will test more later this week.

Comment: To close this out, I was able to successfully run our big dataset through a Dataflow this weekend. Google Support said something was fixed behind the scenes and requested we try it again. This was using the ReadFromBigQuery function.

Thank for the help! I will keep an eye out for 2.33 to be released to see if we can get even better performance.